# Access database on Windows server through VPN from nodejs running on Linux

Tags: node.js, linux, vpn, openvpn

I'm kind of lost in my current project. From a linux machine (Ubuntu server), running a code in nodejs I have to connect to a windows server, through VPN, and access a mySQL server running on it.

About the VPN server I only know it's Windows and I can easily connect to it by using the VPN conector on another Windows machine, I do not have access to that machine or know its parameters.

All I have is the IP of both VPN and database server inside that VPN, and username/password for VPN and database as well. Also I know that the VPN uses `ms-chap v2`.

I'm trying to use openvpn like that:

```
sudo openvpn --remote vpnIP --dev tun --ifconfig 127.0.0.1 dbIP
```

This does not show any error message but never request VPN's username/password

And what should I do from nodejs to access the database once VPN is created?

As I've said, I'm very lost on that! Any tip will be welcome!

Comment: Is the vpn running openvpn as the server software? 

Which Linux distribution are you using?

MS-CHAP in a Windows is commonly used with PPTP-based VPN-servers ( a protocol I strongly advise against), if this is the case you have to use a pptp-client.

Comment: @Hultner I have edited my question. It's a Ubuntu server 16.04. I do not have any information about the VPN server, but the IP and username/passwd. Iĺl take a look to this pptp-client. Never heard about it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless something else is specified, a Windows based VPN almost always uses [PPTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol). You can not connect with OpenVPN. You have to use a PPTP client.

The Ubuntu package is [pptp-linux](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/pptp-linux).
There is a detailed explanation on how to configure it [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PPTP_Client).

In a nutshell (I assume you have no GUI on a server),
you can create a tunnel with :

```
pptpsetup --create my_tunnel --server <server_address> --username <username> --password '<password>' --encrypt
```

Configuration files will be created in `/etc/ppp`. You can then connect (in debug mode) with:

```
pon my_tunnel debug dump logfd 2 nodetach
```

or simply (once it work) :

```
pon my_tunnel
```

and stop it with :

```
poff my_tunnel
```

If the server is a gateway, you may need to add a route, something like :

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev ppp0
```

Comment: This looks promissing, but I can't test it right now. The gateway you refer to is my linux box or the Windows server? But there is an open point: Once the connection is open how do I make my local client to talk to an IP inside the vpn?

Comment: The connection allows you to talk to the (Windows) server. If you want to talk to machines on the remote network, you have to add a route. It basically says "to talk to a machine on <some_network> send the data through the tunnel". In the example the remote network is 192.168.1.0/24, the local network must be something else. This is described http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/routing.phtml#client-to-lan (Client to LAN part). You can also add a default route.

Answer (score 1):

You may want **Network Manager** with  a plugin ***network-manager-pptp***, also see this wiki
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient#PPTP